# How to start different elements on different keyframes of an animation in CSS

Tags: css, animation, keyframe

If I have a CSS animation and I want to create various instances of that animation but start at different stages of the animation how can I specify that.

I imagined something like this, second webkit line is pseudo code:

```
 #cell1
  {
      width:100px;
      height:100px;

       -webkit-animation: pulse 35s infinite alternate;
       -webkit-animation: pulse start at 25%;
  }
```

Comment: here's a good tutorial at [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/97-intro-to-css-animations/)

Comment: Interesting question. I once need to archive a similar result, but ended up "hard coding" the initial status of the element. Would like to know if someone can shed some light on this.

Comment: Passerby, could you give me an example of how you hardcoded the initial status?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I understand the spec, a negative value for `animation-delay` would do the trick:

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#animation-delay

> If the value for 'animation-delay' is a negative time offset then the animation will execute the moment it is applied, but will appear to have begun execution at the specified offset. That is, the animation will appear to begin part-way through its play cycle. In the case where an animation has implied starting values and a negative 'animation-delay', the starting values are taken from the moment the animation is applied.

EDIT: Indeed, this works with my chromium: http://jsfiddle.net/GvUzX/

Comment: This. Feature. Is. Awesome. Thank you so much, this makes my projects so much easier